# Quercus on Google App Engine: Class not loading

Tags: java, php, google-app-engine, quercus

### Fatal Error: no matching class connection

**index.php**

```
<?php
   import database.connection;
   $connection = connection::get()->getPersistenceManager(); // ***ERROR HERE***
?>
```

**connection.java**

```
package database;

import javax.jdo.JDOHelper;
import javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory;

public final class connection {
    private static final PersistenceManagerFactory pmfInstance =
        JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("transactions-optional");

    private connection() {}

    public static PersistenceManagerFactory get() {
        return pmfInstance;
    }
}
```

Quercus is otherwise configured fine, PHP implementation works smoothly on GAE. But when I try to initialize classes, PHP can't find them. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I only discovered that Quercus existed due to you posting this question!

My guess would be that Quercus cannot instantiate the object because the class "connection" has a private constructor.

Looking at the documentation, something like java_class("database.connection") can be used to access static methods in classes which cannot be instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

Your class `connection` needs to extends `AbstractQuercusModule` as explained [here](http://quercus.caucho.com/quercus-3.1/doc/quercus.xtp#module)